# How to change font size, color, type and create bullets when sending a mail from perl script

Tags: perl

I have a perl script which is capable of sending mail to a certain list of users and user reads it in their MS Office Outllook.

I was wondering if it is possible to set the font size, color and type for the mail body and also create bulleted list in the mail body.

Could somebody please help me on that!

Comment: Formatting email so it looks OK on a variety of clients is not trivial. I use Perl's [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) to create [pseudo-tags](https://www.nu42.com/2016/03/macgyver-html-email-perl.html) that take some of the tedium out.

Answer (score 4):

"Rich text" in an email is just HTML. If you can do it in HTML then you can do it in email. Just replace the plain text with an HTML version. And add a "Content-type: text/html" header.

You don't say anything about what tools you're using to create and send the email, so it's hard to be much more help. Except to point out that however you're currently doing it, [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer) will almost certainly make your life easier.